# How can I preserve the url (with the querystring) after an Http Post but also add an error to the Model State?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

Essentially want I'm trying to do is authenticate a user by having them enter their account and their social security number.  If they enter an incorrect combination, I do the following on the `Authenticate` post action:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Authenticated", authenticationError);
return View();
```

This displays the error, but then I lose what was in my query string.  An alternative to keep the query string is:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Authenticated", authenticationError);
return Redirect(Request.Url + "?returnUrl=" + returnUrl);
```

This will keep the query string, but the error will not display.  I assume this is because the `ModelState` has changed.

I need the `returnUrl` because the user is forced to the `Authenticate` page whenever they click to view a specific event.  I want to set it up so that they still go to this event once they authenticate themselves.

Is there a way I can achieve both the preservation of the query string and display the model error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second scenario doesn't have the model state because when you do a redirection the browser makes a separate request to that location, separate requests = new model state.

I would suggest using your first scenario and place a "ReturnUrl" in your model and render it to the client as a hidden field.

```
//In your model add the ReturnUrl Property
public class AuthenticatModel
{
     public string Account {get; set;}
     public string SocialSecurityNumber {get;set;}
     public string ReturnUrl {get;set;}
}



ModelState.AddModelError("Authenticated", authenticationError);
//Set the return URL property before returning the view
model.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
return View(model);


@* add the return URL as a hidden field to your view so it can be posted back *@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReturnUrl)
```

Comment: Or just pass in the return url using the [ViewBag](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem) to avoid polluting your pretty model.

Comment: On the contrary, putting it in the model makes it more clean, because  looking at the model will show you what is needed to be on the view. The viewbag obscures your implementation.

Comment: Thank you!  This works great!  If I were to go the `ViewBag` approach, how would I keep from losing the `returnUrl` if the user isn't authenticated properly?  From what I've seen, `returnUrl` will become `null` if a user doesn't authenticate properly on their first attempt.  Am I missing something with this?

Comment: If you choose to use `ViewBag` you'll have to write out the hidden field in the form area of your view, then on the next request in your controller method interrogate the `Request` object for the form field "ReturnUrl".

Comment: i have same situation here ,and i dont get how setting ReturnUrl in hidden field solved this issue ? is he redirecting to ReturnUrl via javascript ? in this situation there will be no model validaiton message displayed ?

Answer (score 10):

[Ivan Korytin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789238/query-string-param-is-missed-when-form-validation-fail)'s answer was the best (and only answer I could find which seemed to actually work properly without using hidden field hacks) which I've [improved a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789238/query-string-param-is-missed-when-form-validation-fail#51194195) with `Request.QueryString`.

You have to put the parameters as part of the form action:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("CreateEntity", "Employee")?@(Request.QueryString)"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

When you perform the following the query string (and `GET` parameters) are now preserved:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyAction model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: if Request property is unavailable -> `@Context.Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

For **ASP.NET Core**
You can use asp-route-* attribute:

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
```

**Other in details example:**
Imagine that you have a Vehicle Controller with actions

Index

Details

Edit

and you can edit any vehicle from Index or from Details, so if you clicked edit from index you must return to index after edit
and if you clicked edit from details you must return to details after edit.

```
//In your viewmodel add the ReturnUrl Property
public class VehicleViewModel
{
     ..............
     ..............
     public string ReturnUrl {get;set;}
}



Details.cshtml
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-previous="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.CarId">Edit</a>

Index.cshtml
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-previous="Index" asp-route-id="@item.CarId">Edit</a>

Edit.cshtml
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-route-previous="@Model.ReturnUrl" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="box-footer">
            <a asp-action="@Model.ReturnUrl" class="btn btn-default">Back to List</a>
            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

In your controller:

```
// GET: Vehicle/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id,string previous)
    {
            var model = this.UnitOfWork.CarsRepository.GetAllByCarId(id).FirstOrDefault();
            var viewModel = this.Mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(model);//if you using automapper
    //or by this code if you are not use automapper
    var viewModel = new VehicleViewModel();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(previous)
                viewModel.ReturnUrl = previous;
            else
                viewModel.ReturnUrl = "Index";
            return View(viewModel);
        }



[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(VehicleViewModel model, string previous)
    {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(previous))
                model.ReturnUrl = previous;
            else
                model.ReturnUrl = "Index";
            ............. 
            .............
            return RedirectToAction(model.ReturnUrl);
    }
```

Comment: I added an example, i hope it will be helpful

Comment: This isn't really valid for the tags on the question - TagHelpers were added in [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro). Might want to make a note of that in your answer.